# How to run a Windows.Forms C# program from Terminal in OSX?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, winforms, mono

I have to use System.Windows.Forms for my C# course in school but I own a Macbook and Visual Studio says that it doesn't exist. I read that I could use WinForms if I installed **Mono** and then compile and run it from terminal using `mcs hello.cs -pkg:dotnet`. "hello.cs" is just a Hello World program using System.Windows.Forms... it compiles but when I do `mono hello.exe` it says:

```
WARNING: The Carbon driver has not been ported to 64bits, and very few 
parts of Windows.Forms will work properly, or at all
```

... and then a bunch of stuff that I will leave it here in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZvXrhRqZ)!

In the OSX | Mono website they say that in order to use Windows.Forms the architecture of Mono must be 32bits and to change it I have to do: `mono --arch=32` but when I do it, it doesn't seem to do anything and if I compile it and run again the "hello.exe" it prints the same thing I mentioned before.

Please help me! My Mac is old and running Windows on it is not an option.

Comment: I don't have a Mac and don't really have any idea but I'll ask the simple question: did you recompile and try to run again or just run again?  I don't know if that will help, but I figured it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Yes man, I tried that and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling the [`hello.cs`](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/getting-started-guide/) code with the older `mcs` compiler:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mcs -pkg:dotnet ./hello.cs
```

Or use the newer Rosyln-based `csc` compiler:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/csc ./hello.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.3.1.61919 (57c81319)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Run it with `mono` with the `--arch=32` option:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono --arch=32 ./hello.exe
```

Or use `mono32`:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono32 ./hello.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for answer man! It worked perfectly after some minutes.