# Can I install Mono on my Mac Catalina 10.15.4 safely and configure Mono 32 if needed?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, winforms, mono

I wanted to use Mono in my Visual Studio for Mac in order to run some programs coded with System.Windows.Forms namespace. These programs make use of functions like GetOffset etc.

I have Mac Catalina 10.15.4 and I wanted to know if I can install Mono for Visual Studio on Mac and even then run the above applications and if so how to use Mono 32 bit(How to fire command --arch=32)? I am a newbie to Mono.

Thanks

Comment: You can not use 32-bit apps in Catalina, you could setup a  VM via Parallels or Fusion using older macOS version, but at that point you might as well use a Windows-based VM to run the original WinForms program

Comment: So o didn’t understand: 32 bit mono won’t work on Mac? Can’t I somehow toggle between 32 / 64 bit mono in my Mac? And is there any newer version mac that supports fusion etc? Also how do I build a win based vm?any pointers are appreciated

Comment: No 32-bit apps work on Catalina+

Comment: Ok, but I found this on net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126322/how-to-run-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-program-from-terminal-in-osx. Will this work by supplying mono --arch=32 in Mono?

Comment: As is also listed in https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6701 that You can use mono32 to run the app with 32bit Mono for now.

Comment: You did not read that whole thread, using arch-32/mono32 does not work on Catalina+ , but there is "mac-playground" that is "64 bit" that provides a 64-bit Cocoa backend for Mono's Window Forms project
https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6701#issuecomment-570968861 How well it works I do not know as Mono's Windows Forms on macOS/Linux never really worked at that well

Comment: Ok then I will go ahead with VM for windows on my Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following first comment "You can not use 32-bit apps in Catalina, you could setup a VM via Parallels or Fusion using older macOS version, but at that point you might as well use a Windows-based VM to run the original WinForms program", I decided to use Windows OS rather than Mac as my Catalina version is >10. Closing this thread